# C++ using STL List, how to copy an existing list into a new list

Tags: c++, list, stl, linked-list, long-integer

Right now I'm working with a copy constructor for taking a list called val of type char, and I need to take all the elements of a string v that is passed into the copy constructor and put them into the val list.

```
Public:
LongInt(const string v);

Private:
list<char> val;
```

So here in the public section of the LongInt class I have a copy constructor which takes the val list and copies the v string into it.  Can anyone help me figure out how to do this?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might want to think about the choice of a list of chars is really the best container to use. It fragments the memory quite heavily, as well as having quite a big overhead.

Comment: `LongInt(const string v);` is not a copy constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `LongInt` constructor just use the `iterator, iterator` `list` constructor:

`LongInt(const string v) : val(v.begin(), v.end()) { }`

That being said, have you considered actually using `string` or possibly `deque<char>` to manipulate your sequence rather than `list`? Depending on your needs, those alternatives might be better.

Comment: Also, taking the argument by reference will be slightly better (remove one copy of the string, which incidentally will most probably be a lesser cost compared to the number of memory allocations needed for the list...)

Comment: The signature should be changed to `const string & v`, to prevent an unnecessary copy. Also, it seems strange to choose a `deque` here. A `vector` has much less overhead.

Answer (score 5):

You'll have to iterate over the string and extract the data character by character. Using the `std::copy` algorithm should work:

```
std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter(val));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
LongInt::LongInt( const string v ) : val(v.begin(), v.end())
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, use `std::string` if it's a string you're storing. It's a container like any other. If you can't or don't want to store a string, use `std::vector`. But that would boil down to a less-functional `std::string` anyway, so just use `std::string`.

For the copying:

```
std::copy( v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter(val) );
```

But just use a `std::string` if it's a list of `char`s you're storing.